# Fail/pass Jenkins job by email notification

Tags: email, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

We have an in-company system for creating production builds, and I need to create a Jenkins job to automate those builds.

There is a way to automate the *launch* of production build. But you can only know the *results* of the build by an email notification. Furthermore, you can only subscribe to notification using your personal domain credentials, i.e. the same login/pass that you use to log into your computer (and the password changes every month).

So now, Jenkins job is considered "pass" as soon as the build *launches*, and not when it actually finishes.

I wonder how to make Jenkins pass/fail the job with the given restrictions.

Additionally, I want to avoid:

- hardcoding my personal credentials anywhere,
- depending on my or anyone else's personal computer being turned on.

Ideas?

Comment: What's the type of the builds you launch? How do you launch them? I assume the machines you launch them on is not a Jenkins slave, right?

Comment: @GeroldBroser, you are right, actually I just launch a few .bat files on remote machines. The final outcome is the new version of the library in the internal npm registry.

Comment: Do the programs called inside the `.bat` files set `ERRORLEVEL` depending on their success or fail? Or can you adapt the files to set it accordingly?

Comment: The programs inside the `.bat` files exit too early - as soon as they started (or failed to) the build process.

Comment: Its not a matter of "too early", it's a matter of whether they return a status code on exit. What is displayed if you add `echo %errorlevel%` immediately after a programm call in the `.bat` files?

Comment: They exit with 0 if build was _started_ successfully, and 1 if _starting failed_. And they know _nothing_ about the final success or failure of the process that they start.

Comment: I see. That's bad. Such we don't have a chance to use the status code. However, see the update to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31496687/1744774).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Jenkins plugin that is capable of receiving e-mails.

If you can manage to store the notifications' content in a file you could use the 
[Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) in the Post-build Actions of an additional monitor job that runs on a regular basis.

Have a look at [Monitoring external jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs), too,  whether this is useful for you.

#### UPDATE:

There is actually a plugin that receives e-mails: the [poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/poll-mailbox-trigger-plugin). Install it and do the following:

- Create a new **Freestyle project** named e.g. *Build Status Mail Monitor*

  - **Build Triggers** → [✔] [Poll Mailbox Trigger] - Poll an email inbox

    - *configure as desired*
  - **Build** → **Add build step** → **Execute Groovy script**

    - ◉ Groovy command: *add code to change build launcher job's status*

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like Text-finder Plugin can't "wait" for the results to appear. And in my case it may be up to 20 minutes before launch and notification.

Comment: @GeorgiyIvankin That's why I wrote _"an additional monitor job that runs on a regular basis"_ – every 20 mins, for instance.

Comment: I see now. But there will be too many such jobs launched for one build - hard to say which job relates to which build. And what to do if the results are not there yet? Fail? Or pass? It's too ambiguous.